# Toy Line (Production) Run

Tags: word-meaning, ellipsis

I am not sure about the meaning of this:

> [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Generation_1)
>   Transformers: Generation 1 (also known as Generation One or G1) was a children's toy line that ***ran*** from 1984 to 1991 and was produced by Hasbro.

Would the following rewrite be better?

> [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Generation_1)
>   Transformers: Generation 1 (also known as Generation One or G1) was a children's toy line ***the production of which*** ***ran*** from 1984 to 1991 and was produced by Hasbro.

Comment: The rewrite would be explicitly clearer. Whether or not it's better is open for debate :)

Comment: @user8543 So, the original is poorly written?

Comment: No. A native speaker would understand it just fine, and one word is better than five. But yours is clearer to someone unfamiliar with the language, I'm sure.

Comment: From a past few questions, I assume that you are fond of pleonasm!

Comment: @user8543  But "*toy line*" is a group of toys.  "*Run*" means an activity continues.  So "*a toy line that ran from 1984 to 1991*" seems to be missing something.

Comment: technically it's missing 'the production of which', but like many contractions, the meaning is understood by a native speaker where it would be obscure to someone new to the language.

Comment: @user8543 Could I write "the Ford Crowd Victoria ran from 1911 to 2011"?

Comment: Not in that specific case, because a car can 'run' in a different sense of the word. You could say the Ford Crown Victoria _line_ ran from X to Y however. A 'line' is a range of products.

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence is making something explicit that is implicit in the first sentence. But because it is easily inferred from the first sentence, the first sentence is not incorrect or incomplete.

As an example, consider the sentence:

> *Blake's 7* was a television show that ran on the BBC from 1978 to 1981.

Technically, what you are saying is that the broadcast of episodes of the show ran from 1978 to 1981; this is also known as a **broadcast run.** As with a **production run**, "run" can be used as a shorthand.

Comment: That was a great show.